# Can I attach one of my Google docs to an email?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account. I think it would be convenient to store some documents as Google docs and then include them as attachments in my emails.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=58225

1. Open the doc or file you'd like to share.
2. Go to the **File** menu, and select **Email as attachment**....
3. Select a file type from the drop-down menu.
4. Enter the email address of the people to whom you'd like to send the doc or file. If you'd like, you can also add a subject and a message.
5. Click **Send**. People to whom you're emailing this doc will receive it as a downloadable attachment in the file format you selected in Step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail now lets you [insert multiple files from Drive/Google Docs directly into an email without leaving your Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/gmail-and-drive-new-way-to-send-files.html).